# Dealing with control flexibility

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-web-gui

I've a question more about 'Good Programming Practices'. 
I have just started a really big project. I'm using WebGui (long story short.. it is WinForms in web) - but it's not important.

I'm creating milions of forms with milions of controls like `TextBox`, `NumericUpDown`, `DateTimePicker` and etc. It might happen, that I will have to change something in behavior of `DateTimePicker` or appearance. It will be impossible to change it in every control. I want my project to be flexible so I've got an idea..

I do separate custom controls for every type - string, numeric, date, byte.. and within I will put TextBox for example. And on every form I will put not TextBox, but MyTextBox. In fact, that MyTextBox will be just TextBox, but when I change something there, every control will be changed.

Is it good, popular pracitce in programming?

Comment: It might be easier to suggest an answer when you use realistic numbers. I doubt you'll be creating millions of forms with millions of controls. Is there a document describing the application functionality? How often are changes like these expected to be made?

Comment: Well, I can't show you this document. I would say more than 200 forms for sure, so for me it is "milions". I don't know how often.. When my client will change his mind, and will say that datetimepicker sux.. yes, he will probably pay for it, but I don't want to waste whole week for that kind of job.

Comment: No need to show the document, it's just important that you have one. It's important to ask for your client's opinion during development, to avoid these situations as much as possible. Perhaps it is possible to achieve those possible changes with CSS? It depends on the type of the change.

Comment: But no CSS. I have to handle it in WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the case of WPF this can be achieved quite easily using Styles and Templates.
in Winforms this is not possible, therefore I'd say your approach of deriving from the controls and using your own custom controls on the UI is a good practical approach which helps managing changes centrally.

If the controls were created manually in the programme, alternatively you could use a Factory clase(s) and get the Factories to create the controller object rather than just newing up.
But this might not be possible when the UI is created by dragging and dropping controls as the  developer has no control over the creation of controls.

Which ever the approach you choose, the fundamental goal should be to centralize the creation logic of the controlls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly normal programming practice for GUI development, if the standard controls don't satisfy your requirements.

Most developers get 3rd party control suites for the extra flexibility. The benefits in buying far out weigh the benefits in building core controls yourself.

I've worked at a place that did companyTextBox, companyDatePicker and it worked ok. A couple of controls got revamped over .Net versions so these base classed controls required some surgery. Any depreciated controls were left as framework version dependent.

For special things, I do a lot of research into good custom controls on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43181/A-Serious-Outlook-Style-Navigation-Pane-Control), CodePlex, Code.Google.com,etc and implement them into the project I'm working on. 
Otherwise use the stock standard controls or the suite of 3rd party controls the company I'm working for use.

My advice is to get a 3rd party suite of controls and make a ton of re-usable user controls based on the 3rd party ones. This way you can build most of the 200 forms by Drag and Dropping the user controls onto the forms. Make each User-Control Implement an Interface with Create,Retrieve,Update & Delete methods for the forms to generically work with your user controls.